# JSONata to alter array of object and rename name keys

Tags: jsonata

Trying to alter an array of object with JSONata, addresses names need to be altered and some items are not used at all, what I can tell is if I alter the array it make groups them into an individual array like lineOne would be `[{"MY HOUSE1","SUITE 11-1111"}]` and the if function does not work the way I would assume it should.

Source:

```js
{
    "customers": [
        {
            "title": "DR.",
            "firstName": "FRED",
            "middleName": "L.",
            "lastName": "BEERMAN",
            "suffix": "MR.",
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "addressLine1": "MY HOUSE1",
                    "addressLine2": "1366 ELM LANE",
                    "city": "EAST GREENBUSH",
                    "state": "NY",
                    "zip": "800131234",
                    "county": "SCHENECTADY",
                    "countryCode": "US",
                    "addressType": "RESIDENCE",
                    "sendMail": true,
                    "key": "0"
                },
                {
                    "addressLine1": "SUITE 11-1111",
                    "addressLine2": "1366 ELM LANE",
                    "city": "EAST GREENBUSH",
                    "state": "NY",
                    "zip": "12061",
                    "county": "SCHENECTADY",
                    "countryCode": "US",
                    "addressType": "SHIPPING",
                    "sendMail": true,
                    "key": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Expectation:

```js
{
    "customers": [
        {
        "title": "DR.",
        "givenName": "FRED",
        "middleName": "L.",
        "familyName": "BEERMAN",
        "nameSuffix": "MR.",
        "addresses": [
            {
            "addressType": "RESIDENCE",
            "lineOne": "MY HOUSE1",
            "lineTwo": "1366 ELM LANE",
            "cityName": "EAST GREENBUSH",
            "stateOrProvinceCountrySubDivisionId": "NY",
            "postCode": "800131234",
            "countyCountrySubDivision": "SCHENECTADY",
            "countryId": "US",
            "privacy": [
                        {
                            "okToContact": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                "addressType": "SHIPPING",
                "lineOne": "SUITE 11-1111",
                "lineTwo": "1366 ELM LANE",
                "cityName": "EAST GREENBUSH",
                "stateOrProvinceCountrySubDivisionId": "NY",
                "postCode": "800131234",
                "countyCountrySubDivision": "SCHENECTADY",
                "countryId": "US",
                "privacy": [
                        {
                            "okToContact": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I have tried:

```js
"customerParty": {
    "givenName": customers.firstName,
    "middleName": customers.middleName,
    "familyName": customers.lastName,
    "title": customers.title,
    "salutation": customers.title,
    "addresses":[
        customers.addresses.$each(function($value, $key) {
            { 
                $key ? 'addressType' : 'addressType:' $value,
                $key ? 'addressLine1' : 'lineOne:' $value,
                $key ? 'addressLine2' : 'lineTwo:' $value,
                $key ? 'city' : 'cityName:' $value,
                $key ? 'countryCode' : 'countryId:' $value,
                $key ? 'zip' : 'postCode:' $value,
                $key ? 'state' : 'stateOrProvinceCountrySubDivisionId:' $value,
                $key ? 'county' : 'countyCountrySubDivision:' $value,
                $key ? 'sendMail' : '"privacy": [{"okToContact": $value}]:' ,
            }
            }) ~> $merge()
        ]
    }
```

Also

```js
"address":[
    {
        "addressType": customers.addresses.addressType,
        "lineOne": customers.addresses.addressLine1,
        "lineTwo": customers.addresses.addressLine2,
        "cityName": customers.addresses.city,
        "countryId": customers.addresses.countryCode,
        "postCode": customers.addresses.zip,
        "stateOrProvinceCountrySubDivisionId": customers.addresses.state,
        "countyCountrySubDivision": customers.addresses.county,
        "privacy": [
            {
                "okToContact": customers.addresses.sendMail
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [map operator](https://docs.jsonata.org/path-operators#-map) like this:

```js
{
    "customerParty": {
        "givenName": customers.firstName,
        "middleName": customers.middleName,
        "familyName": customers.lastName,
        "title": customers.title,
        "salutation": customers.title,
        "addresses": customers.addresses.{
            "addressType": addressType,
            "lineOne": addressLine1,
            "lineTwo": addressLine2,
            "cityName": city,
            "countryId": countryCode,
            "postCode": zip,
            "stateOrProvinceCountrySubDivisionId": state,
            "countyCountrySubDivision": county,
            "privacy": [{ "okToContact": sendMail }]
        }
    }
}
```

Check it out on the Stedi playground: https://stedi.link/VOR9BFi

Comment: Thank you for this, I have one more issue, how could I append, additional addresses if they are not in the original array of addresses, say in the root.

Comment: Would you mind providing an expected input and output? That can help me answer your question accurately

Comment: In the meantime, I suspect you're looking for something like this: https://stedi.link/P3O6jjK